# Remove last line in select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

How do I remove last row from selected data. I need to sort a data and order it. But last row is never used. maybe someone knows an exemple?

Comment: Maybe this question needs a little more detail???

Comment: if you are storing this data at server side, you can remove the last row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try like this

```
select * from table
where rowid<>(select max(rowid) from table);
```

or

```
select * from table
minus
select * from table where rownum = (select count(*) from table)
```

Comment: There for I am selecting from select, your suggestions are great.

Comment: This is an awful answer. I can think of many situations where the row with the maximum rowid will not be the last one returned from a query, even from one which is just a full table scan. The second query is just nonsense, as the result will simply be SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE (DISTINCT due to the MINUS clause). That second clause will only return any data when there is one row in the table.

Comment: I am using 
RANK() and OVER
so I don't need a rowid and I think MAX() works quiet well.

Answer (score 6):

you can try this

```
with t as (select 1 field from dual
union all 
select 2 from dual)

select * from (
  select count(*) over(order by field desc) cnt, t.* from t
) 
where cnt != rownum
```

Comment: I don't think that the "order by field desc" is required there.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have some query that returns a certain number of rows, you can use COUNT(*) OVER () to find out how many rows it is returning. To eliminate the final row you must push the query into a subquery and filter on the ROWNUM ...

```
select ...
from   (select   count(*) over () total_rows,
                 ...
        from     ...
        where    ...
        order by ...)
where   rownum < total_rows
```

Comment: This won't work as it should if some rows are being deleted. So, be carefull.

Answer (score 1):

see this problem if yours is similar [MySQL: How to select all rows from a table EXCEPT the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315621/mysql-how-to-select-all-rows-from-a-table-except-the-last-one) and see this code there

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID != (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE)
```

here "ID != (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE)" this part cuts the last row which have the highest number in serial(for this, you have to declare an integer field(ID) which will be auto_increment.that field will give you the largest value on the last row of the records by MAX(ID))