# Sum of all cells in mysql column except last row

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting sum of all cells in column with following query..

```
$result = mysql_query("select SUM(previous_balance) as balance from table_name ");
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);   
 $item_number = $row['balance'];
 $total1 = $item_number ;

 echo $total1;
```

But I want to Omit last cell value in SUM. How can I do it ?

Comment: Without an ORDER BY clause, referring to the "last" row doesn't really make sense.

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).**

Comment: select the last value in a new query in the same transaction and deduct that value. Or use UNION to get both values in one query? Or create a stored procedure. Many options available.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you want to get?

Comment: @pcguru ur suggestion "select the last value in a new query in the same transaction and deduct that value" worked for me...thnx

Comment: @darshan: have your table any date-time fields?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315621/mysql-how-to-select-all-rows-from-a-table-except-the-last-one) (if I'm reading it right), the following should work to select all except for the last row, and then to use that to sum over all items

```
SELECT SUM(previous_balance) as balance FROM table_name WHERE my_primary_key <> (SELECT MAX(my_primary_key) FROM table_name);
```

Comment: In case primary key is `1,2,3...` not random!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: `MAX(my_primary_key)` will work only if the key field have a incremental values. In smart tables, key field have values like `379fosi3w03kjfls389`.

Comment: He means, if the pkey field is something like a UUID and not an auto_increment, this method will not work.