# MySQL get records without last record

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a query to get records from MySQL table as below.

```
SELECT * FROM alerts
```

i have this columns id is primary and auto increment

```
id,host,domain,alert_time
```

But i need to get records without last record of this table, anyone know how to write a MySQL query for that. Thank You

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of "last" record (or "first" record or "second" record) unless another column specifies the ordering.  Do you have such a column?  When asking a question, you should include sample data and desired results.

Comment: i have a primary  key called id which is auto increment

Comment: Agreed with @GordonLinoff. Unless the exact meaning of "last record" is defined, the question is unclear, and will lead to diverse answers based on diverse interpretations.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315621/mysql-how-to-select-all-rows-from-a-table-except-the-last-one

Comment: ^ @BeingSunny didn't found that before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative method is:

```
SELECT *
FROM alerts a
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1,99999999
```

I like Manish's answer better for removing the largest id, but there are circumstances where this would be appropriate.  For instance, if you wanted all but the most recent three records, it is easier to do using this method.

(Note:  The `99999999` is just a large number to get the rest of the rows.)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Sir can you please explain about the large number i mean `LIMIT 1,99999999`?

Comment: @BeingSunny . . . I thought I did.  The `1` is the offset.  This starts at 0, so "1" means skip the first row.  The 99999999  is the number of rows to fetch.  The large number is big enough to get the rest of the rows.  You have to put a constant there, so it is just a big number.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, OMG, how i missed it `ORDER BY id DESC` on your query, that's why i was little confused about `limit 1,99999999`. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 5):

Try this way to get your `MAX` value of `id` column and then select all rows except it.

```
SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE ID != (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM alerts)
```

Comment: How did know the the last row have the highest ID?

Comment: Because its auto incremenet

Comment: make a column id and make it auto increment if your table does not have any auto increment field