# Mysql select all but first and last row

Tags: php, mysql

I want the database to show all the rows, except for the first and last ones, since I have CSS code for them.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM db 
WHERE 
keywords LIKE '%example%' LIMIT 9999 OFFSET 1
 AND 
keywords LIKE '%example%' DESC LIMIT 9999 OFFSET 1
```

Since the row number may increase I can't write an exact number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to select all rows from a table EXCEPT the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315621/mysql-how-to-select-all-rows-from-a-table-except-the-last-one)

Comment: It is strongly advisable that you handle this with PHP code, to avoid making 2 or more request

Comment: Hi @Kakotas, if the provided answer below solved your issue, could you mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Cyril Done, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is no reason to complicate your query by trying to snip off these values at the SQL level, you could do:

```
$results = $db->query( /* regular query with all results */ );

array_pop($results);
array_shift($results);

// Now use $results, which now contains only the "middle" content
```

If you really want it at the DB level, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM db 
WHERE keywords LIKE '%example%' 
AND id <> (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE)
AND id <> (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: I find this to be the most sensible answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID != (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE) LIMIT 1,9844674507370
```

But like I said in the comment : It is strongly advisable that you handle this with PHP code, to avoid making 2 or more requests

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` like as

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE keywords LIKE '%example%' order by keywords ASC limit 1 UNION SELECT * FROM db WHERE keywords LIKE '%example%' order by keywords DESC limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using `LIMIT` AND `OFFSET`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id != (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name) AND id != (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_name)

SELECT * FROM db 
WHERE 
keywords LIKE '%example%'
AND
id != (SELECT MAX(id) FROM db) 
AND 
id != (SELECT MIN(id) FROM db)
```

here id will be your auto increment key

Answer (score -1):

**1st :** Simple you can handle this thing in php like below . avoid two query

```
 $last_record =count($records)-1;
 $i=0;
   foreach($records as $key=>$row)
   {
      if($i==0){
           //apply the css
       }

      if($i== $last_record ){
           //apply the css
       }
   }
```

**query :**

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE keywords LIKE '%example%'
```