# Mysql, delete all except for last entry

Tags: mysql

I am migrating data from one MySQL Database to a NoSQL DB (like Mongo or something similar). What I have is something like this:

```
 ------------------------
| id | lead |   event    |
 ------------------------
| 1  | 333  |  event1    |
 ------------------------
| 3  | 333  |  event2    |
 ------------------------
| 22 | 333  |  event3    |
 ------------------------
| 9  | 111  |  event1    |
 ------------------------
```

what I want to do is delete delete all entries except for the last entry. So after the delete command I would be left with:

```
 ------------------------
| id | lead |   event    |
 ------------------------
| 22 | 333  |  event3    |
 ------------------------
| 9  | 111  |  event1    |
 ------------------------
```

I would like to mention that it's against MySQL8.0 some of the other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315621/mysql-how-to-select-all-rows-from-a-table-except-the-last-one) I have [looked at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470230/sql-selecting-all-but-the-last-row-in-a-table) are 8+ years old and don't allow for some of the structures, while others don't work as expected, namely that they return all rows from the query

also I am using a "select" statement to see if I can return the values before I delete

Comment: Have you tried to select `MAX(id)` grouped by `lead`? You can then delete `where id not in ...` (as long as the id is a unique key).

Comment: `id` indicates a surrogate key, such as an identity column. Such surrogate keys are Not guaranteed to be in order and should Never be used for determining time series order. Always use another column for that; surrogate keys / identity columns should Only ever be used for unique identification of a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
DELETE t1 
FROM table t1 
JOIN table t2 USING (lead) 
WHERE t1.id < t2.id
```

Comment: is there a way that I could test this using the same `SELECT` statement to avoid importing the database multiple times?

Comment: @Ctfrancia Of course. Replace `DELETE t1` with `SELECT t1.*` - and you'll see the rows which will be removed.